# Accessing to a Textview from a class (not an activity)

Tags: android

I have a main activity that extends AppCompatActivity, this activity can easily access to the TextView, than I have another java class that I need to access to the same TextView... I couldn't find it out!

Comment: you can make the TextView public and static like so

Comment: public static TextView myTextView;

Comment: and in your onCreate

Comment: myTextView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

Comment: then you can use that TextView in other classes like so

Comment: MainActivity.myTextView

Comment: you can also wrap it in a not null ckeck

Comment: DO NOT make the textView public and static.  This causes a memory leak.  Pass it into the other class when needed as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would be better to keep Android framework objects (especially those that extend Context (Views, Activities, Fragments, etc.) isolated from the rest of your code whenever possible.

Instead of exposing the TextView to your "plain" java object, it would be better to define an interface, devoid of Android Context, and pass that to your 'plain' java object.

Another effective strategy is to use a message bus (or RxJava subject acting as a bus), to communicate between the Activity containing the TextView and the plain java object. e.g. Let the plain java object tell the Activity to change the TextView's content via a message.

Answer (score 3):

**Check the code below:-**

**In your Activity :-**

```
TextView txtview = (TextView)findviewbyId(R.id.tv);

MyJavaClass jav = new MyJavaClass();

jav.setTextView(txtview);
```

**Now in your Java Class :-**

```
class MyJavaClass {

TextView tv ;

public void setTextView(TextView view){
this.tv = view;
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

At first , why do you want to access a TextView from another class directly?

Is that class an Activity , Fragment or just a java class?

Although, 
You can create a **static** TextView and you can access it in another class.
But be careful of activity lifecycle, if activity stopped so TextView's reference will be null.

Finally don't use static.

According to OOAD it's better to Don't pass TextView to another class.

Why my answer got -1 ?

Comment: Accessing a textview in another class isn't so weird-  there's a few good reason including helper functions and Strategy patterns.  But never hold a static reference to a view-  a view holds a reference to the activity.  Holding a static reference to an activity will cause that activity to leak.  The correct answer is to pass it in via constructor/method parameter, and not to pass it to anything that isn't scoped to the Activity.

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't recommend static reference too. It's better to communicate with interface. Although pass it on constructor is good choice too